# GSheet MINVERSE is limited for a private user?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get an inversed matrix using Sheets MINVERSE array formula and found the following.

When my matrix size is less or equal to 5x5 matrix, let's say:

```
 2       -1        0       -1        0
-1        3       -1        0       -1
 0       -1        2        0        0
-1        0        0        2       -1
 0       -1        0       -1        3
```

function "=MINVERSE(C13:G17)" works and gives the result.
For 6x6 matrix it throws #NUM! error, saying that the matrix should be square.

I haven't found any information about limitations for the private user, is it a bug or something?

Comment: MINVERSE works fine to me with 6x6 arrays. Please provide an example where the function doesn't work.